# Write grayscale BMP to ZIP file from Memorystream

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, dotnetzip, grayscale

I'm trying to test whether writing individual images or a bundle zipped is quicker.  My approach is to create a random byte array of values between 0 and 255 (8-bit image) and form a Bitmap from it, writing repeatedly using Bitmap.Save.  In this way I can set the PixelFormat to Format8bppIndexed, which gives a grayscale image:

```
// Random number Generator
Random rnd = new Random();

// Create a single image
int Width = 640;
int Height = 512;
var b = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
ColorPalette ncp = b.Palette;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    ncp.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(255, i, i, i);
b.Palette = ncp;

var BoundsRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
BitmapData bmpData = b.LockBits(BoundsRect,
                ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                b.PixelFormat);
IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
int bytes = bmpData.Stride * b.Height;
var rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

// fill in rgbValues, e.g. with a for loop over an input array
rnd.NextBytes(rgbValues);

Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
b.UnlockBits(bmpData);

// copy image to a list of ~1000
List<Bitmap> bmps = new List<Bitmap>();
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    bmps.Add(new Bitmap(b));

// Write to individual files
DateTime t0=DateTime.Now;
for (int i=0;i<bmps.Count;i++)
    b.Save(@"C:\Temp\DiskTransferTest\IndividualImages\" + i.ToString() + ".bmp");
DateTime t1=DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Time to write individually: " + (t1-t0).ToString());
```

After that, I try and zip them all into a single ZIP file and save, using DotNetZip.  This works, but I get a colour image rather than a greyscale one, so the filesizes are much larger.

```
// Create memorystreams from bitmap to pass to DotNetZip
List<MemoryStream> mss = new List<MemoryStream>();
for (int i = 0; i < bmps.Count; i++)
{
    mss.Add(new MemoryStream());
    bmps[i].Save(mss[i], ImageFormat.Bmp);
    mss[i].Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}

// Compress and write
t0 = DateTime.Now;
using (ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile())
{
    zipfile.CompressionLevel = 0;
    int i=0;
    foreach (MemoryStream ms in mss)
        {
         string pictureName = i.ToString() + ".bmp";
         zipfile.AddEntry(pictureName,ms);
         i++;
        }           
    zipfile.Save(@"C:\Temp\DiskTransferTest\zipped.zip");
}
t1 = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Time to write compressed: " + (t1 - t0).ToString());
```

Any suggestions on how to write a greyscale to the zip via the MemoryStream?

Comment: Testing zip compression with random data is a bad idea.  Randomness compresses very poorly.

Comment: This test isn't about the compression, it's about writing a single large file instead of thousands of smaller ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your new bitmaps aren't 8bpp bitmaps. Consider your code:

```
// copy image to a list of ~1000
List<Bitmap> bmps = new List<Bitmap>();
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    bmps.Add(new Bitmap(b));

// Write to individual files
DateTime t0=DateTime.Now;
for (int i=0;i<bmps.Count;i++)
    b.Save(@"C:\Temp\DiskTransferTest\IndividualImages\" + i.ToString() + ".bmp");
```

The bitmap `b` is an 8bpp bitmap. You're writing it to file. But if you examine `bmps[0]` I think you'll find that the `PixelFormat` is 32bpp. At least, that's what happens when I execute this code:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(640, 480, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
Console.WriteLine(bmp.PixelFormat); // 8 bpp
var bmp2 = new Bitmap(bmp);
Console.WriteLine(bmp2.PixelFormat); // 32 bpp
```

In your code that writes the bitmaps to the memory stream, you're accessing `bmps[i]`, rather than the 8bpp image, `b`, as you are when writing to file.

You need to create your list bitmaps, set their properties, and then copy `b`. You can't duplicate the bitmaps with their properties with the `new Bitmap(b)` constructor call.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that line. An alternative that would probably work is to call `(Bitmap) b.Clone()` instead of `new Bitmap(b)`.

Comment: Ahh, I hadn't considered that the properties would change.  I used Ahlo's method of calling (Bitmap) b.Clone() and it worked a treat.  Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible to create a **true** grayscale image using the `Bitmap` class. You would have to exchange the `Bitmap.Palette` property from the present `ColorPalette` to a `GrayscalePalette` that would only store one byte per color instead of the four bytes needed per ARGB color. The framework does not contain any such class, `ColorPalette` does not inherit a base class or implement an interface, and it's also sealed so you can't inherit from the class either.

On the other hand, checking the bitmap file format specification I see that there is no way to save a **true** grayscale bitmap image (using a 256 byte color table). Saving an 8 bit grayscale image in Photoshop CS6 and then opening it again shows that it was saved as a 8 bit color indexed image (although R = G = B for all colors in the palette).